# KEYCODE_SEARCH not working on Nexus S

Tags: android

I am trying to disable device's Search button while showing Dialog.

`keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH`

This is not working for Nexus S device.
Does anyone have an idea how to it can be done on Nexus S device?
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Provide a little more code and show us [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: in which method have you checked the condition?

Comment: Have you considered printing out all the keys pressed to see if the key is mapped to something else?

Comment: @Jomoos:  public boolean onKey( DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) { if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH){return true;}return false;} it is in OnkeyListner of dialog Builder.

Comment: @android developer: i checked it in onKeyListener of dialog builder

Comment: @ArtB : i checked out back key, menu button also. its gives keycode like 4 and 82 but search key didnt gave any keycode on press event.Devices Android version is 4.1.2

Comment: I too have this problem; neither onKey or onSearchRequested implementations seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

never used it , but try [onSearchRequested()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#onSearchRequested%28%29) .

Comment: how about onKeyShortcut,  onKeyDown , or onKeyUp  ? also , have you tried catching the events within the activity instead ? or maybe make an activity that looks like a dialog (using a theme) ? how about a DialogFragment instead ?

Comment: i tried to catch events using onKeyDown within activity but its not working at all. It was not catching any events within activity when Dialog is shown.It was catching events only in onKeyListener of dialog builder.

Comment: did you try the other solutions i've suggested ?

Comment: even using an activity instead of a dialog ? sadly since i don't have a nexus s , i can't test it , but this really looks like a weird case . do you have a custom rom perhaps ?

Comment: Sorry, but what is custom rom ?

Comment: here's an article of what is a custom rom : http://www.androidpolice.com/2010/05/01/custom-roms-for-android-explained-and-why-you-want-them/ . if you don't know what it is , maybe you don't have one , especially on nexus S which has a pure google experience .

Comment: Nice article.As you said,I dont have custom ROM.

Comment: kindly try the other solutions i've suggested : onKeyShortcut, onKeyDown , onKeyUp , activity that is themed as a dialog (via the manifest) , DialogFragment

Comment: can you plz tell me how to use above function? because i m unable to apply it on dialog...

Comment: which one ? i've mentioned multiple solutions . i'd suggest checking the activity solution (which is themed as a dialog) , as it's probably possible to catch the key via a normal activity .

Answer (score 0):

On Nexus S with Android 4.4.4 (Cyanogenmod) one has to change the behaviour of the SEARCH key in the system settings.

Make sure that on short presses it has the function "in app search", and not "search assistant" or something else.

You can test it with the bundled Apollo app which will react on the key once you have found the correct setting.